# Reading and writing text files

Tags: file, python-3.x, text

I have to work with a text file like so:

```
<KeyPlat> = 1228.3
<KeyTran> = 690.3
<KeyTotal> = 1918.6
<KavPlat> = 2996.3
<KavTran> = 3811.4
<KavTotal> = 6807.7
```

I'm attempting to use this data to write to a new text file with expected output like this:

```
Table 1
Platform    1228.3
Transfers   690.3

Table 2
Platform    1918.6
Transfers   2996.3
Total       6807.7
```

I am trying to just pull the numbers out and store them to write to a new file. The method I was using was to search for key characters and when I do start pulling the numbers. I'm not sure where to go from this point though.

```
def foo():
      # Open write and read files.
      f1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
      f2 = open('to.txt', 'w')


      f2.write("Table 1"\n)
      f2.write("Platform\t")
      #Start of digit information
      searchquery = '='
      #End of digits
      searchquery2 = '<'
      for line in f1:
            for letter in line:
                  if letter is not isdigit():

                  if letter == searchquery:

                  if letter == searchquery2:
```

Comment: Why is `Total   1918.6`  missing from the first table stanza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking character by character I would suggest using the keyword `in` on the line. You can then use `split` to easily generate a list of words which were between whitespaces for instance `["<KeyPlat>", "=", "1228.3"]` would be the outcome of `"<KeyPlat> = 1228.3".split(' ')`. And then you just need to format your output like you prefer. I prefer .format notation.

I was using `lines` as a short cut. You should instead use your file.

```
lines = ["<KeyPlat> = 1228.3", "<KeyTran> = 690.3", "<KeyTotal> = 1918.6"]

f1 = open("testtable.txt", "w")

for line in lines:
    values = line.split(' ')
    if "KeyPlat" in values[0]:
        print("{0:10s}{1:10s}".format("Platform", values[2]), file=f1)
    elif "KeyTran" in values[0]:
        print("{0:10s}{1:10s}".format("Transfers", values[2]), file=f1)
    elif "KeyTotal" in values[0]:
        print("{0:10s}{1:10s}".format("Total", values[2]), file=f1)

f1.close()
```

---

Output:

```
Platform  1228.3    
Transfer  690.3     
Total     1918.6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a rudimentary transformation task tailor-made for quick treatment via [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr).  I just copied and pasted the sample data and output into `xform.txr`, then added directives and variables:

```
$ txr xform.txr data
Table 1
Platform    1228.3
Transfers   690.3
Total       1918.6

Table 2
Platform    2996.3
Transfers   3811.4
Total       6807.7
```

Code in `xform.txr`:

```
@(collect)
<@{prefix}Plat> = @plat
<@{prefix}Tran> = @tran
<@{prefix}Total> = @tot
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat :counter (table 1))
Table @table
Platform    @plat
Transfers   @tran
Total       @tot

@  (end)
@(end)
```